# definition of url in web.xml and ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, struts2, url-mapping

i have a problem mapping my `url` to reach the `servlet class`. i'm calling the servlet by `getJSON` function but the simple `sysout` doesnt work.

in my jsp i put:

```
$.getJSON('getMediaListByMediaType/options?dd=' + ddId + '&val=' + $('#mediaType:selected').text(), //some other codes here)
```

in my web.xml, i have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<javaee:display-name>MediaScratch</javaee:display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dropDownServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jp.co.aeonbank.servlets.LoadDropDownServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dropDownServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getMediaListByMediaType/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

as i checked in google developers' tool, it actually can get the correct url but says it is not found

```
http://IpAddressHere/ProjectNameHere/getMediaListByMediaType/options?dd=mediaNo&val=DVD-R
```

any idea why? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I figured out that the reason why it cannot reach the `servlet` is beacuse the FilterMapping for struts2 catches all the `url` that's why `servlet-mapping` became useless. In order to prevent the process of entering in default struts2 filter, i have defined this piece of code on my struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/getMediaListByMediaType/.*"/>
```

Now it can successfully get the `JSON` from my servlet class.